# Create a desktop widget (like Yahoo Widgets or Google Gadgets) with Qt 4

Tags: c++, widget, qt4, desktop

How do I create with Qt 4 a window that remains anchored to the desktop as a widget ?
(e.g. like Yahoo Widgets or Google Gadgets).

I intend to give the same characteristics of a widget to a  normal window:

1. Remove the edges (easy to do)
2. The window must not move (how ?)
3. Must be displayed only when other windows are minimized (how ?)

Comment: I thought that desktop widgets belong to the desktop environment (e.g. KDE), not UI toolkit which is used to implement the desktop. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(KDE)#Supported_Widgets Or?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think setting these flags will do what you are looking for:

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnBottomHint);
```

1. Remove the edges ---> `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` will remove the edges
2. The window must not move ---> (AFAIK) you can't move window when `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` flag is set
3. Must be displayed only when other windows are minimized ---> `Qt::WindowStaysOnBottomHint` will keep the application window below all other windows

Comment: This doesn't work in Qt 5.9 on Windows. Despite having `Qt::WindowStaysOnBottomHint` set, the widget is shown above all other windows.

Comment: Which Windows (7/8/10) are you using? I tested it with (perhaps) Win7 then.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Qt provides anything specific to do this. You will need to create and manage your own window but you can use [`QDesktopWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html) to help.